# tex4ht conversion of tables (memoir class problem)

Tags: memoir, conversion, html, tex4ht

I am trying convert my document to HTML using htlatex. Everything my document (70+ pages) works fine until I look at the tables. The tables generated do not actually follow any kind of table format.

Here is my minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{9cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Column Name} & \textbf{Column Description} \\ \hline
Test line 1 & Insert text here (line 1)\\ \hline
Test line 2 & Insert text here (line 2)\\ \hline
Test line 3 & Insert text here (line 3) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

In command prompt, I use:

```
htlatex.exe MinimalTest.tex "html,3,info" "" "-dhtml" "--interaction=nonstopmode"
```

Note: If I run the same command without "nonstopmode", I receive warning that \halign is translated to linear text and an error saying that there is a missing number, which is then treated as zero. I have tried searching for both of these errors, but did not find solutions that worked.

Edit:
So I can't believe I haven't tried it before, but I changed the document class type and it works as it should. However, the problem is that I need to use memoir for the layout of my PDF. Does anyone know of a workaround to make the HTML generation with memoir work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `memoir` redefines lot of internal latex commands and environments. As `tex4ht` also redefines these commands and environments with hooks to put the `html` codes, the two packages clashes. Best solution would be to create `memoir` configuration for `tex4ht`, but this would be huge task.

Solution at the moment is to switch to `article` class when `tex4ht` is running:

```
\ifcsname HCode\endcsname%
\documentclass{article}
\else
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{memoir}
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{9cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Column Name} & \textbf{Column Description} \\ \hline
Test line 1 & Insert text here (line 1)\\ \hline
Test line 2 & Insert text here (line 2)\\ \hline
Test line 3 & Insert text here (line 3) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

We check for existence of `\HCode` command, defined by `tex4ht`.

As `memoir` defines some new commands, if you use some of them in your document, you also need to provide some definition for them here. For example:

```
\ifcsname HCode\endcsname%
\documentclass{article}
% If you need to add some xml structure, you can use xml tags right here
\newcommand\sample[1]{%
\leavevmode%
\Tg<strong>#1\Tg</strong>%
}
% But it should suffice to use only normal LaTeX commands
\newcommand\simple[1]{%
\textit{#1}
}
\else
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{memoir}
\fi
\begin{document}
\sample{Hello world} and \simple{hello world}
\end{document}
```

which produces following paragraph:

```html
<!--l. 16--><p class="noindent" ><strong>Hello world</strong> and <span 
class="cmti-10">hello world</span>
</p>
```

Note that this is not a clean solution, best option would be to collect these commands in package and create `packagename.4ht` file with redefinitions for `tex4ht`, but in the case of simpler documents showed solution should suffice

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly the information I needed!

Comment: Haha sorry I looked to upvote it but it wouldn't allow me because I didn't have enough reputation. Totally missed the checkmark...