# htlatex with article vs memoir

Tags: memoir, tex4ht, html, htlatex

Why does the following document (with article document class):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
\hline

\hline
5 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

creates a perfect html doc.

While the following (using memoir) produces the error:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
\hline

\hline
5 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Following is the error

```
l.3 --- TeX4ht warning --- \halign translated into linear text ---
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \ar:cnt 
l.4 \hline
```

Note: Both produce completely perfect pdfs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that both `memoir` and `tex4ht` redefines lot of standard macros. `tex4ht` tries hard to translate `LaTeX` tables to their `html` counterparts. In order to do that, it inserts some configurable hooks to standard macros. But it seems that `memoir` also changes standard table macros, in some way which is incompatible with `tex4ht`

This problem can be solved by writing `tex4ht` configuration file for `memoir`. In fact, it exists, but it is really basic and it doesn't contain configuration for tables. You can see it [on the ctan](http://texlive.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/memoir.4ht)

So what is needed at the moment is that someone who understands `memoir` internals and the way in which `tex4ht` handles tables write configurations for `memoir`'s tables and possibly other things, which `memoir` redefines.

---

**Edit**

For start, you can try to include configurations for packages loaded by memoir automatically. Place this file as `memoir.4ht` in directory with your document:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% memoir.4ht                           2009-05-21-09:32 %
% Copyright (C) 2003--2009      Eitan M. Gurari         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is Eitan M. Gurari.                                    %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                             gurari@cse.ohio-state.edu  %
%                 http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2009-05-21-09:32}

\input book.4ht
\input verse.4ht
% Tables Handling
\input array.4ht
\input dcolumn.4ht
\input tabularx.4ht
\input booktabs.4ht
\let\rm\empty
\let\sf\empty
\let\tt\empty
\let\bf\empty
\let\it\empty

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
   \gHAdvance\:mpNum by 1
\HAssign\minipageNum=\:mpNum \relax
%
   {\SkipRefstepAnchor \let\addcontentsline\:gobbleIII\no@chapter[#1]{}%
    \global\let\f@rtoc\f@rtoc
    \global\let\f@rhdr\f@rhdr  }%
   \HtmlEnv   \Toc:Title{#1}\:chapter{#2}}
\NewConfigure{poemline}{2}

\ifx \memgobble\:UnDef
   \pend:defI\getthelinenumber{%
   \let\sv:thepoemline\thepoemline
   \pend:def\thepoemline{\a:poemline}%
   \append:def\thepoemline{\b:poemline}}
\append:defI\getthelinenumber{\let\thepoemline\sv:thepoemline}

\else
   \pend:defII\getthelinenumber{%
   \let\sv:thepoemline\thepoemline
   \pend:def\thepoemline{\a:poemline}%
   \append:def\thepoemline{\b:poemline}}
\append:defII\getthelinenumber{\let\thepoemline\sv:thepoemline}

\fi
\Hinput{memoir}
\endinput
```

Comment: yes i understood that much however i would like to know what to put in the memoir.4ht so that it doesn't cripple my html.. is there someway to inherit tabular from article instead of memoir? Any solution if i have a 1000 page document written using memoir commands and don't have the flexibility to change to article? what would be the easiest way around?

Comment: @RamneekHanda I added sample config file

Comment: thanks for the solution. could you help me with the http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85302/htlatex-need-help-converting-latex-to-html#comment183968_85302 , after making your recommended changes there in that example it fails somewhere else :(

Comment: +1 I really appreciate how much you know about `tex4ht`, thanks so much :)

Comment: ahh cant delete comments.. had put it on wrong post :)